# Cloth crumbles into itself

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

It falls on the cube for a few frames, then it just goes up and crumbles like this. Help please.

file: [image]

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: To do as Chris asks: Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

Comment: done, idk why it does that , also my pc lags a lot when playing the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You self Collison for the falling cloth is way to high, the default value does not work most of the time, try to set the self collision to about 0.001 meters.

Comment: Ok so it is better but still behaves very strange https://imgur.com/X8y2b5A (another project, same bowl settings)

Comment: @xTudor: after changing parameter you have to press "delete all bakes" and then "bake" again. If you do this, you will get: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6EZ.png and it is always a good idea to write that you are a beginner (if you are - and i am sure you are) so we can give more hints we are aware of but most beginners are not.

Comment: @xTudor and if it is another blend file you are testing it with - provide the other blend file

Comment: @Chris ok that worked. but why is that gap between the bowl and the cloth? https://imgur.com/DH1AwJe . (Btw, I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nis7LjTPCwM if you can tell me what am I doing wrong, that would be perfect)